# Jquery Fancyform and IE10: Checkbox does not get checked when clicking on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

So, I have this weird IE10-Bug (IE11 works correctly):

I've got a checkbox like this:

```
<div class="select-row row-b">
    <p>some text</p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroupA" data-index="1" value="A1"/>A1</label>
</div>
```

Using [Fancyform](http://plugins.jquery.com/Fancyform/)-jQuery-Plugin v 1.4.2, it seems there's a bug in Fancyform for IE10:

so pretend this is my checkbox (somewhat styled): [ A1 ]
Clicking somewhere inside the borders ( inside  [ ] ) works. Checkbox is checked. But clicking directly on the Text (the Label, "A1") does not work, checkbox state does not change from unchecked to checked.

I added a console.log("..."); to fancyforms transformCheckbox-method right here:

```
check: function () {
                console.log("setting check");
                method.setProp(this, "checked", 1);
            },
```

just showing me the same. "check" is not triggered, when I click at the label.

It would be great to get some hints here, for I am out of Ideas now.

Best Regards,
Dom

Comment: You mention IE10 and IE11 but no other browsers. Are you saying IE10 is the only one with the problem, or...?

Comment: you may need to add an `id` attribute to the `checkbox` and a `for` attribute to the `label` and set them to the same value

Comment: @LoganMurphy - That's not necessary if the input is inside the label, at least not for standard label behaviour (I don't know what Fancyform does to it).

Comment: it works in ff/chrome/Safari :) We support ie10 and above, so idk if it would work in <=ie9. Apart from that, I actually tried using id/for, but as mentioned above, no change because it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, in this case you need to bind the event because the IE version.

```
$(".select-row row-b label").bind('click',function(){
   $('input',this).attr("checked",true);
})
```

**Edit:** Here's my working code, based on this answer. I edit this code inside here because there are several side effects you have to take care of:

```
this.$rowLbls = $(this.$el.find('.row-alter label')); //might be $('yourdomelement', 'yoursecond...'')
        this.$rowLbls.click(function(event) {
            var ele = $(this).find('input');
            if( $(event.target).is("label") ) { //check exactly for label, because fired twice if not => would work just once
                if(ele.is(':checked')){
                    ele.prop('checked', false); //prop instead of attr for true/false
                } else{
                    ele.prop('checked', true);
                }
            } 
        });
```

Comment: did you add this to the transformCheckbox-function (especially the "check: ..."-part) or whereelse?

Comment: I did put it in my script to work together with the transform checkbox. You can call the "check: function" there

Comment: just worked it out with your help (just had to add the true/false-condition, prop instead of attr and so on) thanks :)